# Is this actually what a podcast mean?

Tags: meaning

So apparently, after researching I found out that podcast means a recorded video that we can hear/view online and we can download it through digital devices such as PC/laptop. But if that's the case aren't all youtube videos considered a podcast? Or am I wrong?

Comment: A podcaster typically issues new podcasts *periodically*, whereas a YouTube video could be a one-off.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: What word or phrase did you not understand?

Comment: Well.. you explained the word using the word podcast which really doesn't make much sense as I am asking for the word podcast not podcaster... Also I would like to know why my question is downvoted?

Comment: Because you did not include your "research".

Comment: I did unless you can't see. O.O

Comment: Where did that definition come from?

Comment: My understanding? That's why I asked if it is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podcasts are often audio only.

They are similar to radio shows which talk about a certain topic for a certain amount of time.

Podcasts may be uploaded to YouTube as a video, but there is usually an audio-only version to accompany it.

I found this definition on dictionary.com:

A digital audio file made available on the Internet for downloading to a computer or mobile device, typically available as a series, new installments of which can be received by subscribers automatically.

Comment: Well there's this video that shows an animated video and audio, so aren't they the same thing? Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KAd3KVSDPpU

Comment: Yes. That is a podcast. There is the video version on YouTube and the audio-only version can be downloaded from iTunes.

Comment: Ah so podcast is audio only, kinda funny how google defines it terribly and complicatedly thank you for your time kind sir.